# Delete every occurrence in a file

Tags: awk, sed

Let's say I have a file with this format content:

```
6 8
6 9
12 20
6
8
9
12
20
35
```

I want to delete all the lines if the number (from 1st or 2nd column) is found in next lines whether it is in the first or 2nd column inluding the line where the initial number is found.

So I should have this as a result:

```
35
```

I've tried using

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a){next};a[$i]}} 1'
```

Is there a simple way to do this ?

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts whatever you tried to solve this problem too in your post in code tags.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 35 and 12 then?

Comment: Edit: forgot to add 12.

Comment: @inourss, always try to add correct samples for input and output in your posts. Also try to encourage people by doing up-votes to their helpful answers. Show your efforts always what you tried to solve the problems too, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, then I would expect the following output `6\n8\n9\n12\n20\n35`. None of these numbers appear in the next lines. Line 4 contains the number _6_. This number does not appear in lines 5 till the end, as is what you stated. Dito for the next lines.

Comment: Or do you want to remove all the lines which contain a number that apears somewhere else in the file.

Comment: @kvantour I want to remove any number that appeared more than once.
So in this case 6 appeared in line 1,2 and 4. It should be removed. Same for the others. except 35 which appeared only once.

Answer (score 3):

This line should help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(a[$i]>1)next}7' 
     RS=" |\n" file RS="\n" file
```

With this input file:

```
100 200 300
6 8
6 9
12 20
6
8
9
12
20
35
```

The one-liner above is gonna output:

```
100 200 300
35
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to find numbers that only occur once. Let me add "42" to your file on the same line as "35"

```
$ cat file
6 8
6 9
12 20
6
8
9
12
20
35  42
```

To find all the number that only appear once:

```
$ tr -s "[:blank:]" "\n" < file | sort -n | uniq -u
35
42
```

But that doesn't show the *line* in the file where they appear, so

```
$ grep -n -Fw -f <(tr -s "[:blank:]" "\n" < file | sort -n | uniq -u) file
9:35  42
```

I added the `-n` option just for effect, to show that we have line 9 from the file.

Answer (score 2):

The code you originally wrote works perfectly under the condition: *print the current line if and only if any of the **previous** lines do not have a number listed in the current line*. However, you do not request **previous** but **next**.

The simples solution for you would be to `tac` the input and `tac` it back.

```
$ tac <file> | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a) next;a[$i]}}1' | tac
```

If you want to use a single `awk` then you have to store the lines first and process them afterward, it is also a bit more cumbersome because :

- you need to count how many times a number appeared
- and you need a double pass algorithm (by running the file twice or storing it in memory)

This gives you the following :

**double pass:**

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR){ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next }'
       { b=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b+=--a[$i] }
       !b; <file> <file>
```

**memory:**

```
$ awk '{ m[NR]=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next }
       END { for (n=1;n<=NR;++n) {
               b=0; $0=m[n];
               for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b+=--a[$i]
               if (!b) { print }
             }
           }' <file>
```

This outputs the expected :

```
6
8
9
12
20
35
```

If you want to remove all lines which contain a number which appears more then ones in the file, then you simply do :

```
$ awk '(NR==FNR) { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next }
       { b=1; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) b = b && (a[$i]==1) }
       b' <file> <file>
```

**note:** from your input you might also be suffering from the windows `\r` problem, so you might want to do `gsub("\r","")` before everything.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk, processes the data once:

```
awk ' 
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {          # process numbers in record
        r[$i]=r[$i] NR OFS        # add NR on a record list array
        if(p=split(r[$i],t)>1) {  # if there are more than one record in r
            for(j in t)           # delete records on the list
                delete a[t[j]]
            f=1                   # flag up 
        }
    }
    if(f=="")                     # if flag is down
        a[NR]=$0                  # store current record 
    f=""                          # reset flag
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)            # in the end
        if(i in a)                # print all records stored
            print a[i]
}' file
35
```

**A revised version:**

```
awk '
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if($i in r) {             # just store the NR of last duplicate
            delete a[r[$i]]
            f=1
        }
        r[$i]=NR
    }
    if(f=="") 
        a[NR]=$0
    f=""
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)
        if(i in a)
            print a[i]
}' file
35
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
cat yourFile | tr ' ' '\n' | sort  | uniq -u
```

Comment: `uniq -u` is what you're looking for, but this does not show the line from the original file.

Comment: Also, you can simplify your sed to `sed -n 's/^ *1 //p'` where the line will only be printed if a replacement as been made.

Comment: Thanks for these hints! For me, `uniq -u` did print these lines, though?!